# Mysql IF и IFNULL функции и индекс

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
   COUNT(IF(se.action = 1, 1, NULL)) AS reviews_phones_count,
   IFNULL(se.category_id, se.source_type_id) AS aggregation_column
FROM TABLE
```

Таблица большая, так вот вопрос: если добавить индекс на поля action и category_id, скорость выборки увеличится ?

Comment: Ну очень странный запрос... такому никакие индексы не помогут. Хотя бы по причине Syntax Error...

Comment: Это часть запроса упущены условия выборки и группировки

Comment: Вопрос именно в том, ускоряют индексы выборку в условиях IF и IFNULL

Comment: Конечно, нет. Индексы ускоряют фильтрацию, связывание, группировку, сортировку и пр., но никак не вычисления в выходном наборе.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду знать !